# 30 arrays in javascript is there an easy way?

Tags: javascript, arrays

let's say if I have 30 car models/names or just whatever....I want to put in an array such as

```
var names = []
```

is there an easy way to put all 30 into an array or I have t type it out one by one like

```
var names = ["subaru","toyota",]
```

and so on and on...

Comment: what is the source of the car name datas ?

Comment: I think it would help if you would explain further: where is the data coming from? Do you specify it by hand in the source code, do you have a file or database? ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there will be a shorter way to do that. After all you have to specify all the elements and the array you want to store them in. Alternatively you may put all models in a single string separated by spaces and then split this string, but I believe the option you propose above is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

If you have an input string data = "toyota subaru", then

```
var names = data.split(" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple parser that would do that for you, and then you would simply copy/paste the whole thing into your JS file. But that might take you longer than simply typing it one by one.

If the car models/names are well structured (they are separated by a single delimiter, like a comma or space), then it might be worth   it to write a simple parser. Then again it's only 30 entities...

Comment: so I guess there's is no easy...sorry I'm really new but what's a simple parser?

Comment: @user1850712 see exebook's answer for an example :)

Comment: ah ok so it's like preg_split in php but splits a certain character....

Answer (score 0):

Yes you have to type in those otherwise how the file would know what is the content of
your names array.

If you have them in an excel file, then you should use simple excel formulas to
postfix and prefix them with double quotes and qomas
then copy the forumla and paste it according to the structure so it could be like:
var myCars=new Array("subaru",
"toyota",
.
.
.
"last car name"
);